# How to skip rows with the same values

Tags: loops, average, stata

I have the following problem: I have a dataset with over 1million entries (shown below), that includes the variables company (=Name of the company (string)) and reviews (=amount of reviews a company received) and company1 (assigns numeric to specific company name). Now I want to calculate the average amount of reviews a company in the dataset receives. But if I just do `sum reviews`then it will count the amount of reviews of company 3 two times, the amount of reviews of company five 23 times etc. (as often as they are listed in the data). How do I avoid this and only count them once?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your image is not readable (by me on a laptop). The Stata tag wiki gives detailed advice on how to give data examples and the command `dataex` bundled with recent versions of Stata is easily used for SE.

The flavour of your request is easier to follow. Here is an analogue. With the Grunfeld data we can calculate a mean investment for each year.

```
webuse grunfeld, clear 
egen mean = mean(invest), by(year)
```

Now we might want to know how many years had `mean` invest above 200 (in the units used)?

```
su mean if mean > 200
```

or

```
count if mean > 200
```

returns the number of observations (not years). If you try it, the result is 30. In the Grunfeld data, there are 10 companies each measured for each year, so dividing by 10 is an easy answer. For more complicated datasets, it would better to tag each year just once, and then look only at tagged observations:

```
egen tag = tag(year) 

count if tag & mean > 200
```

It would be more common to tag panels, not years, but the principle is the same. See the help for `egen`.

`collapse` and `contract` offer other routes, with or without using frames.